# Access all custom data attributes on certain elements

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I want to execute a function on click only from elements that have a custom data attribute (`data-title`) set. Currently they are just `a` and `button` elements.

Why does this code execute on *all* `a` and `button` elements even if no `data-title` is set?

```
$('a[data-title!=""], button[data-title!=""]').on('click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Has Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$('a[data-title], button[data-title]').on('click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: @JaredEitnier Don't feel dumb you have learn't a new thing :)

Comment: @JaredEitnier Yeah, you made me `practice`. And `practice make a man perfect`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [attribute exists selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/)

```
$('a[data-title], button[data-title]').on('click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

why?
In your condition you are checking `data-title!=""`, but if the element does not have the attribute `data-title` the attribute value will be `null` not `""`(empty string), thus the test `result !== check` will return true because `null !== ""`.